# Square rooting of a diagonalizable matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant

Square root of a diagonalizable matrix $A$ can be otained as 
$$B=\sqrt{A}=D \Lambda D^{-1} ~~~~(1),$$ where $$\Lambda=\begin{pmatrix} \lambda_1^{1/2} & 0 \\ 0 & \lambda_2^{1/2} \end{pmatrix}.$$ Here, $\lambda_{1,2}$ are the eigenvalues and $D$ is the diagonalizing matrix od $A$. Recently, in a question:

[Solving a matrix equation of four unknowns](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3267282/solving-a-matrix-equation-of-four-unknowns/3267381#3267381)

Square root of $$P=\begin{pmatrix} 4 & 5 \\ 3 & 6 \end{pmatrix},$$ was required such that $P=Q^2$. The eigenvalues of $P$ are $9,1$, the method (1) and also the the command `MatrixPower[P, 1/2]' of Mathematica gives
$$Q=\frac{1}{4}\begin{pmatrix} 7 & 5 \\ 3 & 9 \end{pmatrix}.~~~~(2)$$
However a brute force method of construction $Q$ from four unknowns $a,b,c,d$ and solutions of the equations thereby along with the conditions that $Trace (P)=Trace (Q^2)$ and $\det(P)=\det(Q^2)$ yields a matrix
$$Q= \frac{1}{2} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 5 \\ 3 & 3 \end{pmatrix}.~~~~(3)$$
Can one explain why does the method in (1) and the  Mathematica igonres (3)? How to resolve this ?

Comment: The matrix square root isn't unique, as your example clearly illustrates (it is true that a symmetric and positive definite matrix has a unique symmetric and positive definite square root, but that breaks when the matrices aren't symmetric.)  What is your actual question here?

Comment: @Brain Borchers, Thanks, the question is how does one get (3) from the method (1).?

Comment: To underscore @BrianBorchers comment, how many matrices $A$ are there such that $A^2=I$?

Comment: @BrianBrochers You may also see dan_filea's solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us diagonalize explicitly. 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
4&5\\3&6
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 5 \\ 5 & -3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
9&\\&1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 5 \\ 5 & -3
\end{bmatrix}^{-1}
\ ,
$$
A square root of a slightly more general shape is then:
$$
Q=
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 5 \\ 5 & -3
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
\pm 3&\\&\pm 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 5 \\ 5 & -3
\end{bmatrix}
^{-1}
\ .
$$
Then the four matrices obtained in this way are:
$$
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
-\frac{7}{4} & -\frac{5}{4} \\
-\frac{3}{4} & -\frac{9}{4}
\end{array}\right]
\ ,\
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
-\frac{1}{2} & -\frac{5}{2} \\
-\frac{3}{2} & -\frac{3}{2}
\end{array}\right]
\ ,\
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
\frac{1}{2} & \frac{5}{2} \\
\frac{3}{2} & \frac{3}{2}
\end{array}\right]
\ ,\
\left[\begin{array}{rr}
\frac{7}{4} & \frac{5}{4} \\
\frac{3}{4} & \frac{9}{4}
\end{array}\right]
\ .
$$

Comment: #dan_fulea, Yes, this answers it perfectly well. You also add some more educative remarks in this. one:.